# Повелительное наклонение + будущее время — ССП или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

> Добейся правильных вариантов ответа(,) и потом объяснишь, почему нужно то или иное время в каждом случае, почитаешь и переведёшь, если надо.

*Это ССП, запятая в скобках нужна в этом случае и в других комбинациях отдельной фразы с повелительным наклонением и какой-то другой?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Это ССП, запятая в скобках нужна в этом случае и в других комбинациях 
отдельной фразы с повелительным наклонением и какой-то другой?
```

Почему ССП? Это сложное предложение с сочинением и подчинением:

*[Добейся правильных вариантов ответа], и [потом объяснишь, (почему нужно то или иное время в каждом случае), почитаешь и переведёшь], (если надо).*

Артём, видимо, Вы хотели спросить, не однородны ли сказуемые добейся, объяснишь, почитаешь и переведёшь? Это как раз и есть спорный вопрос, Валгина называет такие конструкции переходными, каждый случай следует рассматривать отдельно, исходя из однородности сказуемых, занимающих одно синтаксическое место. В данном предложении сказуемые разнооформленные - в повелительном наклонении и в изъявительном будущего времени, поэтому это разные предложения, а вот *объяснишь, почитаешь и переведёшь* одинаковы по форме и объединены общим обстоятельством **потом**, вот они однородны.

http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-029.htm

Так что запятая нужна. Мне  даже кажется, что союз **а** здесь больше бы подходил по смыслу: сначала добейся ответов, а тогда будешь объяснять, читать и переводить.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! Точно, А лучше! Да, действительно, подчинительная связь тоже есть, просто меня интересовало, можно ли большое предложение разбить на два и на этом основании поставить запятую. Как это было правильно сформулировать? Раз подчинение есть, это в любом случае СПП, получается?

Comment: Общая-то характеристика остаётся та же - сложное с разными видами связи - сочинением и подчинением. [Добейся правильных вариантов ответа], и [потом объяснишь...] - сочинение, а придаточные соединены параллельно. Получается, первое соединено с СПП сочинительной связью.